# How to set the URI in a Microprofile RestClientBuilder Provider in Quarkus

Tags: resteasy, quarkus, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

I'm using the Microprofile RestClientBuilder in a Quarkus extension.

I'm using a custom provider that implements the *ClientRequestFilter* interface.

I want to set the URI in the filter with this method:

```
ClientRequestContext.setURI();
```

But, previously I have to set the URI in the RestClientBuilder in this way:

```
RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                 .baseUri(new URI("https://uri.com"))
                 .build(IRestClient.class);
```

Because If I don't set the URI this is the error message from the Builder:

```
Neither baseUri nor baseUrl was specified
```

Any ideas to be able to set the URI in the provider instead in the builder?

**UPDATED**

Stacktrace without URI

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither baseUri nor baseUrl was specified
        at org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.client.RestClientBuilderImpl.build(RestClientBuilderImpl.java:178)
        at com.dummy.remote.rest.CustomRestClientBuilder.build(CustomRestClientBuilder.java:63)
        at com.dummy.remote.rest.CustomRestClientBuilder.newBuilderWithMicroservicesSecurity(CustomRestClientBuilder.java:84)
        at com.dummy.remote.rest.CustomRestClientBuilderTest.testGreeting(CustomRestClientBuilderTest.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.test.QuarkusUnitTest.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusUnitTest.java:341)
        at io.quarkus.test.QuarkusUnitTest.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusUnitTest.java:309)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:188)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
2021-05-26 17:02:51,924 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus stopped in 0.052s
```

With a Mock:

```
.baseUri(new URI("http://foo.bar")).build(IRestClient.class);
```

It works. It seems weird, but it works.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to set it in the builder and override it in the filter ?
Can you post the stacktrace ? I wonder if the error is not directly from the builder, if it is, no choice, set a dummy URL on the builder and override it in the filter.

Comment: I've updated my post with the stacktrace of the result. With a dummy URL works. It's something weird but it works....Thanks

Comment: Great, so looking at the stacktrace this is what I suspected, the error comes from the rest client builder that mandates an URI. So you have no choice other than provides a dummy one.